# Javascript Apply xsl on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xslt

I would like to apply a xsl(in the same js path)  to a javascript variable(contains  valid xml value) and assign the result to another variable.  Working on chrome should be fine.

Comment: You may be interested to know about Saxon CE : http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried pure javascript,  xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlvar) is  undefined.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Saxon CE seems like a better option, but i would prefer pure js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome support the same approach:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(yourVarWithXml, 'application/xml');

var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'sheet.xsl', false);
req.send();
proc.importStylesheet(req.responseXML);

var transformationResult = proc.transformToDocument(doc);
```

That gives you the transformation result as a DOM document, depending on your needs you might want to transform to a fragment of the current HTML document e.g.

```
var fragment = proc.transformToFragment(doc, document);
```

so that you can then do

```
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: It works. Finally I serialize the result to xml string:                                        var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(transformationResult)